# GFI triping with dog bone adapter

Tags: receptacle

I want to use dog bone adapter,  (2) 30A male Rv to 50A female. Also a 15/30 on one of the 30A male legs.
The problem you might have guessed is the GFI. Your thoughts please.

Comment: Are you sure it is tripping for a ground fault? As if  each of the 30a RV plugs are on separate leg that is still way under sized for a RV50 amp this would violate code also I can see multiple reasons for faults.

Answer (score 2):

So many problems:

- 2 x 30A @ 120V = 1 x 30A @ 240V. But that is less than 50A @ 240V. You may say "but the breaker will trip at 30A, so what's the problem?" The problems (there may be others...) are that (a) normally loads are allowed at 80% for continuous usage, so you could have a 30A continuous (or more, as much as 40A - but 30A won't trip the breaker) load when it should max. out at 24A continuos load, and (b) breakers don't trip right away except at high loads, so you could have a legitimate (for 50A) 40A load that will take a while to trip the 30A breaker but potentially cause problems along the way.
- 2 x 30A @ 120V = 1 x 50A @ 240V. But that presumes that they are on a double-breaker to provide common trip. No guarantee of that. So an unbalanced overload (30A on one leg, 50A on the other leg) will trip one breaker but not the other, leading to all sorts of possible dangerous situations when trying to resolve the problem.
- 2 x 30A @ 120V = 1 x 50A @ 240V. But that presumes that they are on different legs. If they are on the same leg then there are major neutral issues (which GFCI *in the right place* would catch) and if you don't have any actual 240V loads in use, you may not realize that there is a problem.
- 30A @ 120V = 15A/30A @ 120V. That leaves the 15A receptacle unprotected from an overload up to 30A, unless it has a separate breaker. A GFCI breaker on the 15A receptacle will protect from ground-faults but not from overloads.

So even before you consider the ramifications of GFCI operation, these types of adapters are a **Really Bad Idea**. If anything, the GFCI requirement may be a blessing in disguise as it highlights the issues of using these types of adapters. Just say no.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent answer from manassehkatz, you should understand why GFCIs make your idea basically impossible. A GFCI works by comparing current between the hot and neutral. Normally, current flowing out the hot all comes back through the neutral. If they are out of balance by more than a few milliamps, the GFCI assumes that the current is leaking to ground, possible through a human body, and trips to protect that assumed body.

Now, in your case, you are interconnecting the neutrals after the GFCIs. Now, if you pull current on either 120 volt circuit, the neutral return is split between the two neutrals and, depending on timing, one or both GFCIs will trip. If you pull current for 240 volts, the current flows through both hots and neither neutral and again, they will trip.

As you can see, with the circuits interconnected, there is no way to make this work.